# Can Kubernetes assign threads (for the app inside a pod) to specific CPU cores?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with single binary with multiple threads in that application. Is it possible in Kubernetes to assign specific thread to specific CPU core inside the pod. I am aware of way to limit pod to work in specific cores, but my requirement is to manage thread mapping inside the pod to specific cores. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The lowest level that you can set up **CPU Policies** is at Container level. We can divide a Kubernetes cluster into namespaces. If you create a Pod within a namespace that has a default CPU limit, and any container in that Pod does not specify its own CPU limit, then the control plane assigns the default CPU limit to that container. Visit this [Official Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-default-namespace/) for more reference.

From the inside of the Container, the only possibility could be [RedHat Tuna](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/sec-tuna-cpu-tuning). Tuna commands can target individual CPUs.

The last possibility is the [**Static CPU policy**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/#static-policy)   which allows containers in Guaranteed pods with integer CPU requests access to exclusive CPUs on the node.

Finally, the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276398/kubernetes-cpu-multithreading) is useful for you, regarding multi threads and CPU assignments.