# How many threads is it advisable to have running at the same time in Java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new to multithreading in Java, after looking at [Java virtual machine - maximum number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726871/java-virtual-machine-maximum-number-of-threads) it would appear there isn't a limit to how many threads a Java/Android app can run.  However, is there an advisable limit?  What I mean by this is, is there a number of threads where if you run past this number then it is unwise because you are unable to determine what thread does what at what time?  I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Careful... Android uses a different virtual machine, so information at the link in your question or other information about non-Android JVM's _might_ not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some advisable limits, however they don't really have anything to do with keeping track of them.

1. Most multithreading comes with locking. If you are using central data storage or global mutable state then the more threads you have, the more lock contention you will get. This is app-specific and depends on how much of said state you have and how often threads read and write it.
2. There are no limits in desktop JVMs by default, but there are OS limits.It should be in the tens of thousands for modern Windows machines, but don't rely on the ability to create much more than that.
3. Running multiple tasks in parallel is great, but the hardware can only cope with so much. If you are using small threads that get fired up sometimes, and spend most their time idle, that's no biggie (Java servers were written like this for years). However if your threads are very intensive, making more of them than the number of cores you have is not likely to give you any benefit. (I believe the standard practice is twice the number of cores if you anticipate threads going idle sometimes).
4. Threads have a cost to them. Whenever you switch Threads you switch context, and while it isn't that expensive, doing it constantly will hurt performance. It's not a good idea to create a Thread to sum up two integers and write back a result.
5. If Threads need visibility of each others state, then they are greatly slowed down, since a lot of their writes have to be written back to main memory. Threads are best used for standalone tasks that require little interaction with each other.

**TL;DR**
Depends on OS and Hardware: on servers creating thousands of threads is fine, on desktop machines you should limit yourself to 50-200 and choose carefully what you do with them.

*Note:* Androids default and suggested "UI multithread helper" - the AsyncTask is not actually a thread. It's a task invoked from a ThreadPool, and as such there is no limit or penalty to using it. It has an upper limit on the number of threads it spawns and reuses them rather than creating new ones. Most Android apps should use it instead of spawning their own threads. In general, Thread Pools are fairly widespread and are a great choice unless you are forced into blocking operations.