# Is there a maximum size parameter in Java FixedThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, threadpool

I've been running tests were the size of a Java *FixedThreadPool* is modified as a variable. From researching the *FixedThreadPool* it seems you should be able to have as many threads in the pool as your memory will allow.

My i7 4-core machine easily handles over 4000 "normal" threads, but changing the threadpool size above 1024 deadlocks my tests. The same 1024  threadpool deadlock happens for an M1 macbook and 2-core macbook air. Is there a set max for a the ThreadPool? For sizes until then everything works fine for all machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit does not resides in jvm memory but in OS per user thread (process) limit.
In linux or Mac OS you can check by ulimit -u.
here you can find more info
[Maximum number of threads per process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux)

When you create ThreadPoolExecutor with Executors.newFixedThreadPool( nb ) no Thread is create and only a small amount of memory is require for each thread (perhaps zero if the implementation use a LinkedList or a map to keep the Worker (Thread))

other useful info here
[Maximum number of threads in a JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726871/maximum-number-of-threads-in-a-jvm/7727922)